# Spring Security does not recognize roles - PreAuthorize or Hibernate Problem?

Tags: java, angular, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to get into Spring security with a Spring/Angular stack and found the awsome code of bezcoder which can be looked up here

https://github.com/bezkoder/angular-10-jwt-authentication
and
https://github.com/bezkoder/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-authentication

Signin and signup works, however, I have trouble with the authorisation for certain access points. For instance, I cannot enter the url localhost:8080/api/test/user - if I try I get "Error:Unauthorized"

I think I narrowed the problem down to the handling of roles by the @PreAuthorize annotation. In the following "TestController", the @PreAuthorize("permitAll()"), as set on the public String allAccess() function works,
however, all other functions with @PreAuthorize which refer to a certain role do not. The controller:

```
package com.savetravel.SaveTravel.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.savetravel.SaveTravel.Repositories.UserRepository;


@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepositoy;
    
    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String allAccess() {
        return "Public Content.";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String userAccess() {
        return "User Content.";
    }

    @GetMapping("/mod")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String moderatorAccess() {
        return "Moderator Board.";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String adminAccess() {
        return "Admin Board.";
    }
    
    
}
```

and my WebSecurityConfig

```
package com.savetravel.SaveTravel;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import com.savetravel.SaveTravel.Security.Services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import com.savetravel.SaveTravel.Security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.savetravel.SaveTravel.Security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        proxyTargetClass = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

If I remove the @PreAuthorize annotations for the roles from the functions in the controller everything works (falling back to the WebSecurityConfig, which is not how its meant to be)
I am quite puzzled, as removing the @PreAuthorize annotations and altering the configure() function in the WebSecurityConfig with .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/test/user").hasRole("USER")does not have an effect either say:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/user").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

It seems that the backend doesn't consider roles at all. The only thing I changed is that I use Hibernate H2 instead of MySQL, as it is used in the original code. Consequently, my application.properties looks like that (the original configuration is commented out):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:savetravel;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialize=true

#Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=rootpassword"); 
#PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE DATABASE databasename");
#int result = ps.executeUpdate();
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
# SQL GENERATE CONFIGURATION
#datasource.schema=  the schema sql script to load. By default it is schema-${platform}.sql then schema.sql;
#datasource.data= the data sql script. By default, it is data-${platform}.sql then data.sql;
#spring.h2.console.enabled=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
app.jwt.header=Authorization
app.jwtSecret= loginSecretKey
app.jwtExpirationMs= 86400000
```

with a data.sql:

```
INSERT INTO roles(name) VALUES('ROLE_USER');
INSERT INTO roles(name) VALUES('ROLE_MODERATOR');
INSERT INTO roles(name) VALUES('ROLE_ADMIN');

INSERT INTO users(id, username, email, password) VALUES(777, 'testuser', 'testuser@test.de', '$2a$10$tmPQGqC7XxNmFKwfufGybOxb7HIDA.0lEOtb3ejAiiBn4EfoxI9TK');
INSERT INTO user_roles(user_id, role_id) VALUES(777, 1);
INSERT INTO user_roles(user_id, role_id) VALUES(777, 2);
```

But I can't imagine that H2 is the problem, because the following tests don't fail:

```
    @Test
    public void simpleConstructorTestUser() {
        User testUser = new User("testUser", "test@test.de", "testpassword");
        assertNotNull(testUser.getUsername());

    }

    @Test
    @PostMapping("/user")
    public void userAccess() {

        String userName = testUser.getUsername();
        System.out.println(userName);
        Optional<User> userFromDB = userRepository.findByUsername(userName);
        Set<Role> roles = userFromDB.get().getRoles();

        for (Role role : roles) {
            String roleType = role.getName().name();
            assertArrayEquals(roleType, "ROLE_USER");
        }
    }
```

But maybe I am wrong and it has to do something with H2 instead of MySql?
For the sake of comprehensiveness: My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <groupId>com.savetravel</groupId>
    <artifactId>SaveTravel</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SaveTravel</name>
    <description>TravelApp</description>



    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Many questions, and the embarassing thing is: I have really no idea WHERE TO SEARCH to solve this problem, especially as the code is supposed to work and a collegue of mine seems to have been able to run it without changes. I would be happy if someone could give me a hint where to start my journey, as I think the Spring security application is terrific and I would love to gain a better understanding of security procedures.
So if anyone has an idea, such as:

- tests I could write in Spring or Angular to check certain things
- configurations I could look up (I use Linux, maybe that is an Issue?)
- anything else...
  Thanks in advance!
  Tom

Comment: In sql insert statement of roles you have used 'ROLE_' and in `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")` I think you should use the same name of roles everywhere in your code some thing like this `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` use 'ROLE_' as prefix it might resolve your issue.

Comment: I have test same with my case but with different version of spring boot `2.3.0` and `2.4.0` both gives different in previous version I have to user prefix `ROLE_` and in latest one `2.4.0` I did not use prefix `Role_' . so according to my knowledge you are using `2.3.1` version of spring boot so I think you need to use ROLE_ as prefix.